# Handling overflowing components with semantic ui react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am building a web app using next.js with react and semantic-ui-react for the styling, and I am trying to build a basic layout comprising of a fixed sidebar for navigation and the page content next to it. Initially I was trying to use the Sidebar component but could not get this to work. A user online suggested it's more for mobile usage, so I changed to using a Menu component with the vertical and fixed properties.

I now have a fixed menu but the main page content does not start beside it -- instead it starts behind the menu. The content is inside a container which has an auto margin working from the edge of the document/page, behind the menu.

Things I have tried:

- Using dev-tools and adding padding-left to the content container fixes the issue but if I resize the page the issue returns -- it's not adaptive/responsive.
- Using a grid -- I have added a grid to the components but it has made no difference.

Relevant code:

_app.js

```
    <div>
  <Head>
    <title>Thoughts!</title>
  </Head>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Column>
      <FixedMenuLayout></FixedMenuLayout>
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

FixedMenu.js

```
    <Menu fixed='left' inverted vertical>
  <Container>
    <Menu.Item as='a' header>
      <Image size='mini' src='/logo.png' style={{ marginRight: '1.5em' }} />
      Project Name
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item as='a'>Home</Menu.Item>

    <Dropdown item simple text='Dropdown'>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Divider />
        <Dropdown.Header>Header Item</Dropdown.Header>
        <Dropdown.Item>
          <i className='dropdown icon' />
          <span className='text'>Submenu</span>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item>List Item</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  </Container>
</Menu>
```

How can I get the content to be next to the sidebar? (I.e. the page starts on the right of the sidebar, like it's own frame.)

As an aside I would also like to be able to have the sidebar fixed, open by default but collapsible with the content taking full-width.